# scrape data from a table that has a "show all" button

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape "ALL EQUITIES" table in the following link which has a show all button

https://www.trading212.com/en/Trade-Equities

I should be able to get the expanded table, not just some of the rows before the table is expanded.

here is my code

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

header = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"}

url = 'https://www.trading212.com/en/Trade-Equities'

r = requests.get(url, headers = header)

soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

all_equities = soup.find('table' , class_ = 'I cant find the name of the class')
print(all_equities)
```

Comment: That page doesn't use a `table` element, the data you're looking for is in a `div` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents are actually in a div, not a table. You can grab all of the content by using the class that is on each of the divs.

```
all_equities = soup.find_all('div' , class_ = 'js-search-row')
```

will give you a list of all of the divs with the equities in them.

Answer (score 0):

Give this code a try:

```
all_equities = soup.find_all('div' , class_ = 'd-row js-search-row js-acc-wrapper')
```